# Configuration Builder .newComponent method asking Type

Tags: kotlin, log4j2

I am using Log4j 2.13.1 and im programmaticaly configuring it,
I am creating a Rolling File appender, and I having a problem in the step to put the Policies.

```
val triggeringPolicies =
            builder.newComponent<DON'T KNOW WHAT TYPE TO PUT HERE>("Policies")
                .addComponent(
                    builder.newComponent<DON'T KNOW WHAT TYPE TO PUT HERE>("CronTriggeringPolicy")
                        .addAttribute("schedule", "0 0 0 * * ?")
                )
```

As you can see, builder.newComponent<>() is asking a Type now, and I don't know what to put there, if I leave it without a Type it gives me a error("Not enough information to infer type variable B").

I searched everywhere and didn't found any example using the latest code for Log4j2.

Also, I am using Kotlin.

Thank you.

Comment: I just discovered that it was Kotlin that is adding the Type requirement, i pasted the code in a Java file and it did not asked for the type, I still don't know what to put there.

Comment: I believe the type would be the class of the builder you are using.